# How to insert JSON.parse value into DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How can i append a JSON value gotten from an ajax request to an element?
Below is the value of the result after i parsed it to JSON.

```
{
"result": "success",
"action": "",
"message": "<option value='1'>30 days</option><option value='2'>60 days</option>"
}
```

This is the element

```
<select>
    <span id="o_p"></span>
</select>
```

I have tried `$('#o_p').append(res.message)` where res is the value gotten after `JSON.parse(AJAX_result)` but the value of select remains empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid.

- A `span` cannot be a child element of a `select`.
- An `option` cannot be a child element of a `span`.

Remove the `span`. Append the message to the `select`.

```js
const AJAX_result = `{
"result": "success",
"action": "",
"message": "<option value='1'>30 days</option><option value='2'>60 days</option>"
}`;

const res = JSON.parse(AJAX_result);

$('select').append(res.message)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select></select>
```

Comment: Thanks @quentin that solved the problem. However, i tried to hard code the options inside the span element and it displayed fine.